# File.Move making a copy of file

Tags: c#, .net, file, io

I have some code where I'm attempting to create a temporary file to be used as a zip file.

```
string tempPath = Path.GetTempFileName(); 
string targetPath = 
    string.Concat(Path.GetTempPath(),"//",Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tempPath),".zip");
File.Move(tempPath, targetPath);
```

However a new file is being created instead of moving (renaming) the temp file.

I'm definitely confused...

Kevin

Comment: Call `Path.Combine` and `Path.ChangeExtension`

Comment: Why are you using "//"? Did you mean "\\"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

[FileInfo.MoveTo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.moveto%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
            var newFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(updateLocation).Select(file => new FileInfo(file));

            var workingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            var existingFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(workingDirectory).Select(file => new FileInfo(file));

            newFiles.ToList().ForEach(newFile =>
            {
                var matchedFile = existingFiles.ToList().Find(delegate(FileInfo file) { return file.Name == newFile.Name; });

                if(matchedFile != null)
                {
                    if(newFile.LastWriteTimeUtc != matchedFile.LastWriteTimeUtc)
                    {
                        if(!Directory.Exists(TEMP_DIRECTORY_NAME))
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(TEMP_DIRECTORY_NAME);

                        matchedFile.MoveTo(Path.Combine(TEMP_DIRECTORY_NAME, matchedFile.Name));
                        newFile.CopyTo(Path.Combine(workingDirectory, newFile.Name));
                    }
                }
                else
                    newFile.CopyTo(Path.Combine(workingDirectory, newFile.Name));
            });'
```

Comment: File.Move and FileInfo.Move to both say "Moves a specified file to a new location, providing the option to specify a new file name."

Comment: I've used this method as recently as last week and it gave me the behavior the OP is looking for.

Comment: I'm just saying that it has the same wording as File.Move, which he is using.

Comment: Right on, I apologize for being defensive!

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behavior. If you want the old file deleted, you need to explicitly do that.

Comment: This is [File.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx), not File.Copy.

Comment: Huh?  Nothing I've found in the [File.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx) documentation suggests that it will every do a copy instead of a move.

Comment: Moving is a 2-step process: 1) copy, 2) delete. In this case Delete fails silently.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me.

```
Path.GetTempFileName()
```

will create a new 0 byte temporary file in your machines %TEMP% directory. After the File.Move line is run the temp file is renamed with a .zip extension.

After this you can now use the file:

```
using (var writeStream = new FileStream(targetPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    // CODE HERE

}
```